# Care yields fine products

Tags: phrase, chengyu, equivalent-phrase, saying

Is there a 成语 saying that care yields fine products (eg. care as in cheerfulness)?

I have heard 慢工出细货, but I would like a 成语 to express something like 小心出细货, not sure if this expression id's even correct, perhaps someone can confirm or correct me.

Thanks.

Comment: typo found: 货 -> 活

Answer (score 4):

I believe 慢工出细货 is good enough.

Although it doesn't mention about care explicitly, it is strongly implied as much care have to be given to produce a delicate product (as 细 means 细緻 here),

and it takes time to breed that work (慢工).